# Just stuck in this code, I have to create a math table

Tags: c++, math, numbers, tabular

I have this code which is giving me error, I have no idea how to fix it.
I don't know which part I'm doing wrong.

I have made a code like this but with out giving user a option, 
for example:

```
int counter;
    for (counter=1; counter<=100000; counter=counter+1)
    {
        cout<<"2x"<<counter<<"="<<2*counter<<"\n";
```

this code is giving me a table of 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

main()
{       int counter, number, maxMultiplier;
    {
        cout>> "Please enter the number for which you want a table: ";
        cin<< number;
        cout>> "Please select the multiplier up to which you want a table: ";
        cin>> maxMultiplier;    
    }
    for (counter=1; counter<=maxMultiplier; counter=counter+1)
    {   cout<<number<<"x"<<counter<<"="<<number*counter<<"/n";
        }
    {system("pause");}
    return main();
}
```

The user should be able to enter the number for table they want and how long they wants a table to be. Like all the way up to 2x1=2.........2x10=20

Comment: Your code contains at least two typos (`/n` should be `\n` unless you intended to print a forward slash followed by the letter _n_) and `cin<< number` should be `cin >> number`. You also have not included the full text of the actual error you're getting in the question.

Comment: similar problem 2 times with _cout_, `cout_ >>"Please..."` must be `cout << "Please..."`

Comment: So many bugs.  So few errors cited.  Hard to determine which bug is the anonymous error alluded to.

Comment: and the  `return main();` must be removed of course.

Comment: BTW, you can use `++counter` as the increment in the `for` loop, instead of `counter=counter+1;`.

Answer (score 0):

after cleaning the code and taken into account the remarks of TypeIA and me :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int number, maxMultiplier;

  cout << "Please enter the number for which you want a table: ";
  cin >> number;
  cout << "Please select the multiplier up to which you want a table: ";
  cin >> maxMultiplier;    

  for (int counter = 1; counter<=maxMultiplier; ++counter)
  {
    cout<<number<<"x"<<counter<<"="<<number*counter<<"\n";
  }

  system("pause"); // I don't like, pause does not exist under Linux etc
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend a change to your Coding Style:  Always use substatements (curly braces) after `for` loops.  This technique is know to reduce defects and make maintenance easier.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I did :)

Comment: If you don't like `system("pause");`, try `std::cin.ignore(100000,'\n');`.  This works on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews in case I have the choice I replace it by nothing and start the program on a shell :)